# Как создать POJO класс если поля должны меняться?

Tags: java, json, pojo

Имеется JSON, но поле даты меняется. Как его указать в POJO классе?

[image: Для парсинга]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin):

```
data class Data(val rates: Map<Date, Map<String, Double>>)
```

Останется только правильно настроить десериализатор для даты по шаблону из `yyyy-MM-dd`. Или заменить `Date` на `String`